# Predictive Text MDDropdown with Python's filter Method

Tags: python, filter, kivy, prediction

I am trying to build a predictive text MDDropdown on a KivyMD application. I have an MDTextField in which the user will enter text. As the user writes down his/her search, the MDDropdown should show the items which include the text written down. On selection of any given item, the full text of the selection should be added to the TextField.

I have tried Python's filter method to do such task, however I have not succeeded. The MDDropdown is never opened when text is entered. Also, I have noticed that the filter function looks for exact matches. Is there a way to filter partial parts of a string?

**The Python code is the following:**

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton, MDTooltip
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivy.clock import Clock


class TooltipMDIconButton(MDIconButton, MDTooltip):
    pass

# HOJA DE ACTIVIDADES ################################
class IngActivWindow(Screen):
    menu_cliente = None

    def cliente_dropdown(self):

        clientes = ['Amazon', 'Adidas','Banana Republic', 'Calvin Klein','Coach', 'DKNY', 'Microsoft','Nike', 'Sony']

        if len(self.ids.name_client.text) != 0:
            def filtar_clientes(cliente):
                filtrar_valor = self.ids.name_client.text
                if cliente in filtrar_valor:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            filtered = filter(lambda l: str(self.ids.name_client.text) in l, clientes)

            for valores in filtered:
                print(valores)

            # Create the drop down menu
            for cliente in filtered:
                menu_items = [{"text": f"{valores}"} for valores in filtered]
                self.menu_cliente = MDDropdownMenu(
                    caller=self.ids.name_client,
                    items=menu_items,
                    width_mult=5,
                )
                self.menu_cliente.open()
                self.menu_cliente.bind(on_release=self.set_item_cliente)

    def open_clientes_list(self):
        clientes = ['Amazon', 'Adidas','Banana Republic', 'Calvin Klein','Coach', 'DKNY', 'Microsoft','Nike', 'Sony']
        # Create the drop down menu
        menu_items = [{"text": f"{cliente}"} for cliente in clientes]
        self.menu_cliente = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.ids.name_client,
            items=menu_items,
            width_mult=5,
        )
        self.menu_cliente.open()
        self.menu_cliente.bind(on_release=self.set_item_cliente)

    def set_item_cliente(self, instance_menu, instance_menu_item):
        def set_item_cliente(interval):
            self.ids.name_client.text = instance_menu_item.text
            instance_menu.dismiss()

        Clock.schedule_once(set_item_cliente, 0.5)


# WINDOW MANAGER ################################
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


# MAIN CLASS ################################
class PredictiveDropdown(MDApp):


    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PredictiveDropdown().run()
```

**Kivy code:**

```
<WindowManager>:
    id: screen_manager

    IngActivWindow:
        id: ingActiv
        name: 'ingActiv'


<IngActivWindow>:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: 1, 1
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5 , 'center_y':0.5}
        padding: '20dp'
        MDTextField:
            id: name_client
            pos_hint: {"x":0, 'center_y': 0.5}
            write_tab: False
            size_hint: 0.45, None
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'center'
            hint_text:'Seleccionar Cliente o Prospecto'
            on_text: root.cliente_dropdown()

        TooltipMDIconButton:
            id: client_list
            pos_hint: {"x":0, 'center_y': 0.5}
            valign: 'center'
            icon: 'arrow-down-drop-circle-outline'
            tooltip_text: 'Haga clic para visualizar la lista completa de clientes'
            on_release: root.open_clientes_list()
```

Any suggestions of how to achieve the desired task? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT**
Is there a way to filter by position of the character as well? I changed the *filtered* variable code. Now when I type, I do get a printed list. However if I write 'a' I get all of the elements with an a, such as 'Calvin Klein'. I would like for the program to print only 'Amazon' and 'Adidas'. I already modified my code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DropDown` is never opened because you are using the `iterator` that `filter` produces when you `print` the results of the `filter`. Once an `iterator` is used, it cannot be reused. To fix that, simply remove the lines:

```
        for valores in filtered:
            print(valores)
```

Consider using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html). instead of `filter` to get your `filtered` list.

Two other issues. You are opening the `DropDown` in a loop `for valores in filtered:`, but I cannot see why you are doing that in a loop. And since you are triggering the `cliente_dropdown()` method using `on_text` in the `kv`, it will be triggered again when your `set_item_cliente()` method changes the text. On way to fix that is to disable the `cliente_dropdown()` method when dropdown is changing the text.

Here is a modified version of your `IngActivWindow` class that addresses those issues:

```
class IngActivWindow(Screen):
    menu_cliente = None
    do_dropdown = True

    def cliente_dropdown(self):
        # do not open a dropdown if the text was changed by the dropdown
        if not self.do_dropdown:
            return

        if self.menu_cliente:
            # if dropdown is already open, close it
            self.menu_cliente.dismiss()
            self.menu_cliente = None

        clientes = ['Amazon', 'Adidas','Banana Republic', 'Calvin Klein','Coach', 'DKNY', 'Microsoft','Nike', 'Sony']
        filtered_list = []

        if len(self.ids.name_client.text) != 0:
            prefix = self.ids.name_client.text.title()
            filtered = filter(lambda l: l.startswith(prefix), clientes)
            menu_items = [{"text": f"{valores}"} for valores in filtered]
            if len(menu_items) < 1:
                return
            self.menu_cliente = MDDropdownMenu(
                caller=self.ids.name_client,
                callback=self.set_item_cliente,  # use callback instead of bind
                items=menu_items,
                width_mult=5,
            )
            self.menu_cliente.open()

    def open_clientes_list(self):
        clientes = ['Amazon', 'Adidas','Banana Republic', 'Calvin Klein','Coach', 'DKNY', 'Microsoft','Nike', 'Sony']
        # Create the drop down menu
        menu_items = [{"text": f"{cliente}"} for cliente in clientes]
        self.menu_cliente = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.ids.name_client,
            items=menu_items,
            width_mult=5,
        )
        self.menu_cliente.open()
        self.menu_cliente.bind(on_release=self.set_item_cliente)

    def set_item_cliente(self, instance_menu_item):
        def set_item_cliente(interval):
            self.do_dropdown = False
            self.ids.name_client.text = instance_menu_item.text
            self.menu_cliente.dismiss()
            self.menu_cliente = None
            self.do_dropdown = True

        Clock.schedule_once(set_item_cliente, 0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @John Anderson exactly what I needed, could you please check my answer for a further question? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks a lot @John Anderson , this is just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my cliente_dropdown function to:

```
def cliente_dropdown(self):

    clientes = ['Amazon', 'Adidas','Banana Republic', 'Calvin Klein','Coach', 'DKNY', 'Microsoft','Nike', 'Sony']
    filtered_list = []

    if len(self.ids.name_client.text) != 0:
        prefix = self.ids.name_client.text.title()
        filtered = filter(lambda l: l.startswith(prefix), clientes)

        # Create the drop down menu
        for valores in filtered:
            filtered_list.append(valores)
            menu_items = [{"text": f"{valores}"} for valores in filtered_list]
            self.menu_cliente = MDDropdownMenu(
                caller=self.ids.name_client,
                items=menu_items,
                width_mult=5,
            )
            self.menu_cliente.open()
            self.menu_cliente.bind(on_release=self.set_item_cliente)
```

This works, exactly like I need it. However, dropdowns keep opening one on top of the other. I would like the former MDDropdown to close before the later one opens.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot in advance!